# Openshift Scalable Rails 4 new application renders 503 Server Unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, openshift, haproxy, scalable

I successfully deployed a rails single gear application on openshift a few months ago.  I am now attempting to deploy a scalable application.  After setting up the app, connecting with git, pushing a minimalist project to openshift, I am getting a 503 Server Unavailable error.  After doing quite a bit of research, I speculate my problem may be related to the HAProxy. The following post [here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-host-your-java-ee-application-with-auto-scaling) goes into some detail about the haproxy and dealing with the cfg. I do have the same DOWN gears for my local-gear and backend, working with modifications as suggested on the haproxy.cfg file did not resolve my issue, but the listed blog post is referring to a Java project, so were not comparing same environments.

The app runs as expected on my local host, and rhc via ssh into the app, I can run necessary rake tasks, migrations and what not.

Has anyone else run into a similar problem?  If so has anyone been able to correct the issue?

Comment: A few questions... Are you using a DB? If so which one? We just released a new Ruby2 Rails4 quickstart, did you use that one? Also can you post some of the errors & logs from your application.

Comment: I hate those guys asking a question and then just disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is dead, but had to figure it out anyway. So here's the deal in case if it could help someone. Basically I've found two things that causes problems in scallable rails 4.1.x application.

- As for today there must be `gem 'rake'` defined in `Gemfile` (it will work locally without rake defined, but not on openshift). If you see some `'block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)` error that's probably it.
- You have to define your root route in `routes.rb`, like that for example: `root 'users#index'` - haproxy balancer won't start your ruby gear without root route defined. If you see some `Layer7 wrong status, code: 404` error that's probably it.

If you need some further debugging try going to `http://yourappname-yourdomainname.rhcloud.com/haproxy-status/`. There you can see your gears and their *real* status.

Also make sure you have proper database configuration in `database.yml`. If parameters are incorrect the gear - in most cases - won't start. (Best approach is to put there initial sqlite3 config for testing, and once everything is up again go with your real database.)

As a side note: As for today there is no option to install rails 4.2 on openshift. At least without a community cartridge, but I haven't found any working one. If you see some errors about `rack 1.5.2` that probably means you need to downgrade to to rails 4.1.0. Once everything is up - try going to 4.1.9 and see if it works.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I see you are on openshift.  Here is what I find to work 90% of the time:

First, go to the base directory of your project.  Then add the force clean build marker

```
touch .openshift/markers/force_clean_build
```

Then commit this file to your openshift repo using

```
git add .openshift/markers/force_clean_build
git commit -m "Force clean build"
push -f
```