# Rails error when starting server: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModel Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm going through a RoR tutorial and I have a brand new project.  When I run `rails s` I get this error. I did run `bundle install`. I'm on Windows 7 with Rails version 4.2.3.

```
$ rails s
c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4
0:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModel
Helper (NameError)
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view
/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view
/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view
/base.rb:5:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view
/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_consol
e/template.rb:7:in `<class:Template>'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_consol
e/template.rb:6:in `<module:WebConsole>'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_consol
e/template.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_consol
e.rb:12:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_consol
e.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-consol
e.rb:1:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-consol
e.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:76:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:72:in `each'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:61:in `each'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:61:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler.rb:13
4:in `require'
    from c:/Users/Morgan Davison/Documents/Code/Rails/Learning/RoR4 Essentia
l Training/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/command
s.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: actionpack 4.2 needs rack ~> 1.6.0.
for more information see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021900/uninitialized-constant-actionviewhelpersactivemodelhelper-when-deploying-on

Comment: The `rails` you're running may not match your project. Try `bundle exec rails s` or `bin/rails s`

Comment: I did run `bundle install` and I am using rack 1.6.4.