# Cannont connect to localserver: using rails server, getting error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I do apologize for the noob post, however I am following a course from lynda.com on rails essentials. I've spent the last hour getting all the programs/gems installed.

however when I type 'rails server', i get the following error.

```
 C:\sites\simple_cms>rails server
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:7:in `<class:Template>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:6:in `<module:WebConsole>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
            from C:/sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
            from bin/rails:4:in `require'
            from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

    C:\sites\simple_cms>
```

I have tried installing different versions of rails and railties but that has not helped. I've tried restarting mysql but that doesnt seem to do much.

I feel like i'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance for any input on the situation!

EDIT:

```
APPLICATION: require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module SimpleCms
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
---------------------------
BOOT:
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
-----------------------------
RAILS:
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Comment: whats in your `config/application.rb` on line 7?

Comment: Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

Comment: not sure how to help as I didn't work/recommend to work with Rails on windows, absolutely strange error, this https://www.redmine.org/issues/19419 possibly related.

Comment: Can you post the top of your `config/application.rb` and all of your `config/boot.rb` and your `bin/rails`? Also, FWIW, I've *never* been able to get *any* rails application to run on Windows. I'm about 0 for 15. My usual path to a working environment is to create an Ubuntu VM using VirtualBox ...or just wipe Windows and install Ubuntu.

Comment: Edited original post with what you requested: been trying to install ubuntu but having problems , motherboard has bug and wont boot usb. i've never been able to load linux.

Comment: Thanks. All that looks right. Does your `Gemfile` include `rack`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be missing some required Gems. Check out this other post on Stackoverflow:
[uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper when deploying on openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021900/uninitialized-constant-actionviewhelpersactivemodelhelper-when-deploying-on)

This issue with Nokigiri indicates that you might need to be using Ruby version 2.1:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256

Comment: Thank you Karl:) Downgrading ruby to version 2.1 worked for me. Now I have other errors, but atleast the webhost is up. thanks again!